# NPOS not working after adding the EVM to node config in substrate

Tags: rust, evm, npos

I have implemented the NPOS with EVM blockchain using the substrate.

NPOS working fine but after adding EVM to Genesis config in node the NPOS is not working and the staking election failed.

Smart Contracts working fine on the chain.

```
GenesisConfig {
        system: SystemConfig {
            // Add Wasm runtime to storage.
            code: wasm_binary.to_vec(),
        },
        balances: BalancesConfig {
            // Configure endowed accounts with initial balance of 1 << 60.
            balances: endowed_accounts.iter().cloned().map(|k| (k, 1 << 60)).collect(),
        },
        babe: BabeConfig {
            authorities: vec![],
            epoch_config: Some(nfid_runtime::BABE_GENESIS_EPOCH_CONFIG),
        },
        grandpa: GrandpaConfig { authorities: vec![] },
        session: SessionConfig {
            keys: initial_authorities
                .iter()
                .map(|x| {
                    (
                        x.0.clone(),
                        x.0.clone(),
                        SessionKeys { babe: x.1.clone(), grandpa: x.2.clone() },
                    )
                })
                .collect::<Vec<_>>(),
        },
        staking: StakingConfig {
            validator_count: initial_authorities.len() as u32,
            minimum_validator_count: initial_authorities.len() as u32,
            invulnerables: initial_authorities.iter().map(|x| x.0.clone()).collect(),
            slash_reward_fraction: sp_runtime::Perbill::from_percent(10),
            stakers,
            ..Default::default()
        },
        sudo: SudoConfig {
            // Assign network admin rights.
            key: Some(root_key),
        },
        transaction_payment: Default::default(),
        evm: Default::default(),
        ethereum: Default::default(),
        base_fee: Default::default(),
        dynamic_fee: Default::default(),
        node_authorization: NodeAuthorizationConfig {
            nodes: vec![
                (
                    OpaquePeerId(
                        bs58::decode("12D3KooWBmAwcd4PJNJvfV89HwE48nwkRmAgo8Vy3uQEyNNHBox2")
                            .into_vec()
                            .unwrap(),
                    ),
                    endowed_accounts[0].clone(), // Alice
                ),
                (
                    OpaquePeerId(
                        bs58::decode("12D3KooWQYV9dGMFoRzNStwpXztXaBUjtPqi6aU76ZgUriHhKust")
                            .into_vec()
                            .unwrap(),
                    ),
                    endowed_accounts[1].clone(), // Bob
                ),
            ],
        },
    }
```

Comment: You need to provide some MVP code example. What do you mean by NPoS? `pallet-staking`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sure, NPoS means Nomimated Proof of Stake with pallet-babe and pallet-staking

Comment: hi @MuhammadZaryabRafique i am also trying to add EVM pallet in NPOS can you tell which branch of substrate you have used to add EVM pallet ??? i am facing dependency erros.